# Finding the Metropolitan Area or County for City, State

Tags: python, r, geolocation, geospatial, geocoding

I have following data in a dataframe:

```
... location           amount
... Jacksonville, FL   40
... Provo, UT          20
... Montgomery, AL     22
... Los Angeles, CA    34
```

My dataset only contains U.S. cities in the form of [city name, state code] and I have no ZIP codes.

I want to determine either county of a city, in order to visualize my data with ggcounty ([like here](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggcounty)).

I looked on the website of the [U.S. Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/codes/place.html) but couldn't really find a table of city,state,county, or similar.

Assuming that I would prefer solving the problem in R only, who has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a ZIP code and more detailed info doing this:

```
library(ggmap)
revgeocode(as.numeric(geocode('Jacksonville, FL ')))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Returns `[1] "21 E Union St, Jacksonville, FL 32202, USA` but no county?

Comment: I found out that `geocode("Jacksonville, FL", output="more")$administrative_area_level_2` produces the right result. However, I have NO idea how I can now put it on the map. I assume I have to make another question for that?

Comment: That would be the best. It's getting late here. But If nobody answers that, tomorrow I'll gladly give it a shoot :D